# Wso2: cannot save parameters of DBReport or properties of the Log mediator

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Please tell what am I doing wrong?
I add parameters to the sql statement in DB Report Mediator and then click on Update, so that my parameters would've been saved, but when I reopen my DBReport, there is nothing...
[image: entering parameters and saving]

After reopening:
[image: seems like nothing has been added]

Actually I'm creating REST API for the first time, does anyone have examples?
Is it even possible to do that without Integration Studio?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expression should be `get-property()` [1]. Can you try that.

[1]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/accessing-properties-with-xpath/#get-property-function